# Why is the NSDictionary nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I am passing the label and image of selected cell, to the next view, but when I print the NSDictionary I am getting a nil. Why?

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row])
     self.dicSelected = ["friendname" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row], "friendimage" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.row]]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: dicSelected)
}

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){

        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfilePages

        //let data = sender as! NSDictionary
        //nextViewOBJ.dicData = data
        nextViewOBJ.dicData = self.dicSelected;

    }
}
```

Below is the code for FriendProfilePages

```
var friendname = UILabel()
var friendimage = UIImageView()

 var dicData : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()


 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print("Dictionary: \(self.dicData)")
}
```

Comment: What is NSDictionary nil?

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is too early to access a property set in `prepareForSegue`.  As its name implies, this method is invoked when the view controller is loaded.

In `prepareForSegue` you can access the `destinationViewController` property from the segue, so the view controller has already been loaded and `viewDidLoad` has already executed.

You can access the dictionary in `viewWillAppear:animated:` or, perhaps even better, define a setter function on `dicData` that performs whatever tasks are necessary when the dictionary property is set.

Comment: How would I do the setter function?

Comment: Setters and getters are described in the Swift Book on iBooks

Comment: Also you should use indexPath.item not indexPath.row with a collection view

Answer (score 0):

Just to reinforce what Paulw11 is stating (together with some context):

What you should be aware of is that in prepareForSegue, IBOutlets are not guaranteed to be non-nil. Which means in practice that most times objects cannot be reliably set. Instead you should create data variables on your target view controller and then set the value of the data. What you are currently doing is setting values of the objects rather than passing the data.

It is also not clear that the Dictionary you are trying to pass has any valid content. You can try setting the Dictionary at the class level in your source view controller before passing it to the target. Once you've done that you can try use a breakpoint to evaluate the data in the dictionary on the source before you send it to the target view controller. You can go further and trace the data in the target to be certain it remains valid before you begin using it.

**To fix this:**

On your FriendProfilePages class:

Define a variable to hold the dictionary:

```
var dicData:Dictionary? = nil
```

Then in the prepareForSegue method:

```
//initialize your Dictionary with some data before you assign it
... 
//(I don't know how you are creating the Dictionary but your code above does not show a proper initialization).

//set the data value on the target view controller
nextViewOBJ.dicData = self.dicSelected 
//above only works if you have a valid Dictionary
```

Then in the target view controller just add breakpoints before you use the dictionary and confirm that the dictionary holds the correct data.